# AngularJS lazy module definition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my project I divided angular services in different files, each file/service should belongs to a common module named '`com.mysite.services`', for example:

- ServiceA.js
- ServiceB.js
- ServiceC.js

...and so on

however by defining them in this way:

```
angular.module('com.mysite.services', []).
    service('ServiceA', function()
    {
    });
```

I overwrite the module for each file. In order to solve the problem I defined a wrapper function which will create the module if not defined and return instead a reference to it if defined:

```
function angular_module(name, deps)
{
   var m;
   try
   {
     m = angular.module(name);
   }
   catch (e)
   {
     m = angular.module(name, deps || []);
   }
   return m;
};
```

So, I can simple replace the "." with "_" in the declaration:

```
angular_module('com.mysite.services', []).
        service('ServiceA', function()
        {
        });
```

This solved my problem, but my question is: is there a way to avoid my wrapper in favor of an Angular-ish solution? (it seems so dumb :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is what you will need but you can do something like that

In a dedicated file create this :

```
// Bootstrap.js
angular.module('com.mysite.services', ['com.mysite.services.ServiceA', 'com.mysite.services.ServiceB', ....]);
```

And now for every service you can do something like

```
// ServiceA.js
angular.module('com.mysite.services.ServiceA', []).
   service('ServiceA', function(){});

//ServiceB.js
angular.module('com.mysite.services.ServiceB', []).
   service('ServiceB', function(){});
```

You can now depend on 'com.mysite.services' in your app and all your services will be made accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an App.js

```
var myModule = angular.module('com.mysite.services', []);
```

And in ServiceA.js  :

```
myModule.service('ServiceA', function()
    {
    });
```

Comment: this imply the creation of several global variables (I reported "services" but my approach is applied to controllers and directives too), which I would like to avoid (and are against the philosophy of AngularJS)